# What are some treatment procedures for aortic insufficiency?

Tags: cardiovascular-disease

[Aortic insufficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aortic_insufficiency) is the leaking of the aortic valve of the heart that causes blood to flow in the reverse direction during ventricular diastole, from the aorta into the left ventricle.

What are the modern available treatments for that kind of heart valve disease (whether medical or surgical)?

Answer (score 3):

For mild cases, no treatment is needed.

For more severe cases, ACE inhibitors and diuretics are used as medical treatments. The surgical options are aortic valve repair (valvuloplasty) or replacement with a mechanical or tissue valve.

Replacement carries high risks (1 in 50 patients dies) as it is open heart surgery and also a risk the risk of blood clots and thus needs to be carefully considered, and patients need to take anti-blood clot medication afterwards.

Sources:

[Medlineplus on Aortic Insufficiency](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/000179.htm)

[Mayo Clinic on Aortic valve regurgitation](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/aortic-valve-regurgitation/basics/definition/con-20022523) (different name for aortic insufficiency)

[NHS page on aortic valve replacements](http://www.nhs.uk/conditions/aorticvalvereplacement/Pages/Whatisitpage.aspx)